# I have been struggling to transform this while nested loop into a while only nested loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
int rows = 5;
int row = rows;

    while (row >= 1) {
        for (int space = 1; space <= rows - row; ++space) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int star = 1; star <= row; ++star) {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl; 
        row--; 
    }
```

The outcome should be like this [inverted triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfUWO.png)

Comment: @Jau What is the difference between "while nested loop" and "while only nested loop"?:)

Comment: int row = rows is bad naming practice. Maybe something like curr_row?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm new to coding sorry for my words, what I mean is using while and while only. 
as you can see on my code I used while and for loop

Comment: Why do you care about `while` vs. `for`? I'd argue `for` would be neater here anyway: `for (int row = 5; row >= 1; row--)` Remember `while (x)` is basically the same as `for(;x;)`, it's just semantics. If you want to do this with one loop only you'll need to do some kind of modulo math, but I'm not sure how that makes this any easier to follow.

Comment: @tadman you're right that "for"  would be better on this situation but my school prof. wanted us to make it a while "only" nested loop

Comment: @Nieufz A `for` look in the form `for(init; condition; iterate) { ... }` is the same as a `while` loop in the form `init; while (condition) { ... iterate; }` So, for example, `for (int space = 1; space <= rows - row; ++space) { cout << " "; }` becomes `int space = 1; while (space <= rows - row) { cout << " "; ++space; }`

Comment: Side issue: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, only `while`, even only one while, in order to get you some special attention by your teacher.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int rows= 5;
    
    int place= 1;
    char output='*';
    while (place<= rows * rows)
    {
        printf("%c", output);
        if (!(place%rows))
        {
            printf("\n");
            output=' ';
        }
        if (!(place%(rows+1))) output='*';
        place++;
    }
}
```

This works on the concept that you want a new line every 5 (or `rows`) outputs and, apart from line ends, a change of the output character slightly less often.
It has the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can code this way where you consider the items to be displayed as items of a matrix:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int N = 5;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < N*N) 
    {
        int row = i / N;
        int col = i % N;
        
        std::cout << (row<=col ? "*" : " ");
        
        if (col+1==N) { std::cout << std::endl; }
        
        i++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you like one-liners :)  ```for (int i=0; i<N*N; i++) { std::cout << ((i/N)<=(i%N) ? "*" : " ") << ((i%N)+1==N ? "\n" : ""); }```